# grails payment plugin that is actively maintained and working

Tags: grails, plugins, payment

I am looking to integrate any actively maintained and working payment plugin with my grails application.
Can anyone who has been through this before give some guidance.
My application need is simple: I need various subscription levels(monthly/annual) and I need to be able to retrieve the payment details.

Any help is appreciated

Bala

Answer (score 4):

Bobby Warner just released the [Grails Stripe plugin](https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-stripe) recently.  I haven't used it personally, but I've heard very good things about Stripe's usability, and I know that Bobby is an active, helpful developer who would likely be very responsive to feature requests, feedback, and pull requests.